# Want to use Spring Bean in a Servlet using applicationContext or WebApplicationContext. How can i achieve this

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jpa, servlets

==================web.xml=================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>loginBasic</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>siteMendorLogin.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <!--  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>siteMendorLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.firstApp.servlet.SiteMendorLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>siteMendorLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/site</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->

  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

</web-app>
```

> i have my spring.xml placed in src/main/resources folder, hope that location specifies in web.xml is correct

src/main/java --> package com.firstApp.servlet MyServletLogin.java

```
package com.firstApp.servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import com.firstApp.spring.tx.model.User;
import com.firstApp.spring.tx.user.UserManager;

@WebServlet("/Site")
public class MyServletLogin extends HttpServlet{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserManager userManager;
    Map<String, String> userDetails= new HashMap<String, String>();
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        UserManager userManager = (UserManager) ctx.getBean("userManagerImpl");
        userDetails.put("mayank", "mayank");
    }

     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException{
         //TODO
         //check if cookies with user Credentials are already present 

//       
//
             userManager = (UserManager) ctx.getBean("userManagerImpl");

            List<User> list = userManager.findAllUsers();

         String uid=req.getParameter("userId");
         String uName=req.getParameter("userName"); 
         String userPass=req.getParameter("userPass"); 
         HttpSession session = req.getSession();


         if(userDetails.containsKey(uid) && userDetails.get(uid).equals(userPass)){
             session.setAttribute("userId", uid);
             session.setAttribute("userName", uName);
             Cookie cookie = new Cookie("credential", uid+":"+uName+":"+userPass);
             cookie.setMaxAge(100000);
             cookie.setPath("/callidus/");
             resp.addCookie(cookie);
             resp.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8081/callidus/CookieSent");
         }else{
             session.setAttribute("invalid", "Invalid User Id or password");
             resp.sendRedirect("siteMendorLogin.jsp");
         }

     }



}
```

siteMendorLogin.jsp looks like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>SiteMendor Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Site" method="post">  
        <pre>UserId   :  <input type="text" name="userId"/><br/> </pre>
        <pre>UserName  :  <input type="text" name="userName"/><br/> </pre>
        <pre>Password  :  <input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/> </pre> 
        <input type="submit" value="login"/>  
    </form>  

</body>
</html>
```

> I am not sure, if i am doing it the right way, on tomcat start up, getting below error :

SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 24, 2017 12:37:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Mar 24, 2017 12:37:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 24, 2017 12:37:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/com.myFirstApp] startup failed due to previous errors

> Not even getting welcome file(siteMendorLogin.jsp) that i mentioned in web.xml

=======spring.xml=============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firstApp.spring.tx.dao.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firstApp.spring.tx.user.impl" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc_data" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

=====pom.xml======

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.firstApp.spring.tx</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.myFirstApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>com.myFirstApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

> after adding Maven Dependencies to deployment assembly was able to resolve ContextLoaderListener Error but still issue exist in accessing the service bean in servlet, getting this error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.firstApp.servlet.MyServletLogin threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:125)
    com.firstApp.servlet.MyServletLogin.init(MyServletLogin.java:38)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you're using `Spring`, why are you writing Servlets? Use [Spring Web MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`it seems that you are not deploying Spring correctly in your server

Comment: can you post your spring.xml?

Comment: @Andreas , Have to redirect to some other application with cookies not sure, if can do it using mvc and how

Comment: @RubioRic, not deploying correctly can you elaborate please. Do you mean refering spring.xml in web.xml

Comment: Probably the spring jars are not accesible from your web app. Take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/

Comment: have added spring.xml and pom.xml,

Comment: I'm still not sure if you are copying the necessary jars to your app lib folder. Tomcat can access your spring.xml file, the problem is that it can not find spring-web jars.

Comment: @RubioRic, have added Maven dependencies to deployment assembly and it runs, not anymore getting that ContextLoaderListener error, but the problem in accessing service bean using WebAppApplicationContext is still there

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be some missing dependencies in maven pom. Check if you have following dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Also try by changing param-value to classpath*:spring.xml

Based on the updated error:

The init() method is missing call to super.init(config). Add this call to initialize the servletContext and error should probably go away.

Comment: already have those dependencies....tried checking param-value to classpath*:spring.xml, still not change...getting same error

Comment: I also noticed that you are using "jar" in packaging element of pom. Any particular reason ?

Comment: ohh yes, that should be war, actually i first created service side code now making it dynamic web project.. changing that to war.

Comment: have added Maven dependencies to deployment assembly and it runs, not anymore getting that ContextLoaderListener error, but the problem in accessing service bean using WebAppApplicationContext is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138919/discussion-between-gaurav-and-mayank-jalotra).

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your context-param like the following
1.

```
 <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
       </context-param>
(or)

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

2.
Right Click on the project->deployment assembly->Add->build path entries->maven dependency

reference:
[HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher threw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197237/http-status-500-servlet-init-for-servlet-spring-dispatcher-threw-exception)

Comment: do you mean changing the location of my spring.xml, bcs otherwise i have the same context-param

Comment: spring-configuration file should be in wep-app->WEB-INF->spring.xml

Comment: try to add this spring version , spring and java version should be compatable.
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>

Comment: what java version are you using?

Comment: i am using jdk1.7

Comment: then spring 4 is the compatable version of java 7. Did you try the above version?

Comment: yes i created this project as jpa, now converted it to dynamic web project, able to fetch the database results from test class. Only problem is calling service from servlet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138925/discussion-between-shaik-elias-and-mayank-jalotra).